# Add some text in an alert

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I have these lines of code:

```
let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Compiti trovati", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);     
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){ action in }
myAlert.addAction(okAction);
self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

How can I put the code that follows in the alert message?

```
for index in 0...arr.count-1 {     
     print(MenuViewController.tasksArray[arr[index]].printTask())      
}
```

I want to show all the elements of the array `arr[]` in the message of the alert.
In the array there are 2 elements:

```
[
   (104  -  Interrogazione  -  Fisica  -  10/08/2017  -  Yoloooooo)

   (115  -  Compito  -    -  10/08/2017  -  Commentoooooooo)
]
```

Comment: Obviously without the print method

Comment: Please add an example of the contents of the array and the expected result.

Comment: This is the content: 104  -  Interrogazione  -  Fisica  -  10/08/2017  -  Yoloooooo

115  -  Compito  -    -  10/08/2017  -  Commento

Comment: Please [**edit the question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45519746/edit) rather then add information in comments.

Comment: I only want to know how to put the for in the alert message. You can think that in the array there are some elements like "a","b","c"... It's not important the content, because I think it's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join an array of strings to a single `String` with

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c"]
array.joined(separator: ", ") // -> "a, b, c"
```

To add an heterogeneous array with different types you have to map each object to a string representation, it requires that all objects conform to `CustomStringConvertible`

```
let array : [CustomStringConvertible] = [1, "b", Date()]
array.map{ $0.description }
     .joined(separator: ", ")
```

Comment: I have edited the question and I have an array of objects

Comment: You have to assign the result of the `map`/`joined` line to the `message` property of the alert.

Comment: But if you note in my code where there is the print method I only want to print some elements of the array and not all the elements. (I also tried your code but with an array of objects doesn't work, it says this: " Value of type 'tasks' has no member 'description' ")

Comment: I wrote *it requires that all objects conform to `CustomStringConvertible`*. If they don't you have to make the objects conform to `CustomStringConvertible` by adding a `description` property. To print only a few items you need to add an algorithm to filter the items.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explained my problem very well. In my array there are more than 2 elements, but I want to print that 2 elements; with the print method I take that 2 elements with arr[index] (in this array there are 2 numbers, that are the positions of the elements that I want)

Comment: Senza offesa, if you want a specific answer ask a specific question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151132/discussion-between-marco-and-vadian).